# Xamarin Custom Progressbar renderer problem

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, renderer, custom-renderer

I created a new custom renderer that seems to work, but when I am scrolling up or down something strange happens with the settings. As you can see in the photos, the size of the `ProgressBar` changes.

It happens only on iOS. On Android everything is fine.
Maybe someone could help?

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using ExpensesApp.iOS.CustomRenderers;
using CoreGraphics;
using CoreAnimation;
using UIKit;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ProgressBar),typeof(CustomProgressBarRenderer))]
namespace ExpensesApp.iOS.CustomRenderers
{
public class CustomProgressBarRenderer : ProgressBarRenderer
{
    public CustomProgressBarRenderer()
    {
        this.ElementChanged += CustomProgressBarRenderer_ElementChanged;
    }

    private void CustomProgressBarRenderer_ElementChanged(object sender, 
    ElementChangedEventArgs<ProgressBar> e)
    {
        setColor(e.NewElement);
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ProgressBar> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        LayoutSubviews();
    }

    public override void LayoutSubviews()
    {
        base.LayoutSubviews();
        float x = 1.0f;
        float y = 4.0f;
        CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeScale(x, y);
        Transform = transform;
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
        if (e.PropertyName == "Progress")
        {
            setColor(sender as ProgressBar);
        }
    }

    void setColor(ProgressBar element)
    {
        try
        {
            if (element != null)
            {
                var progress = element.Progress * 100;
                if (progress <= 20)
                {
                    this.TintColor = UIColor.Green;
                }
                else if (progress > 20 && progress <= 50)
                {
                    this.TintColor = UIColor.Yellow;
                }
                else if (progress > 50 && progress <= 80)
                {
                    this.TintColor = UIColor.Orange;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.TintColor = UIColor.Red;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you. I tried but it didn't help. I found another solution.
I don’t know exactly how this is going. But it works the way I want it to. I'm still learning :)

```
 public CustomProgressBarRenderer()
    {
        this.ElementChanged += CustomProgressBarRenderer_ElementChanged;
    }

    private void CustomProgressBarRenderer_ElementChanged(object sender, ElementChangedEventArgs<ProgressBar> e)
    {
        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            e.NewElement.ScaleY = 4;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can mark this answer(click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer) later which will help more people with same problem:).

Answer (score 0):

Set Transform to Control:

```
public override void LayoutSubviews()
{
    base.LayoutSubviews();
    float x = 1.0f;
    float y = 4.0f;
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeScale(x, y);
    Control.Transform = transform;
}
```

And do not call `LayoutSubviews();` in `OnElementChanged`:

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ProgressBar> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);
    //LayoutSubviews();
}
```